# SO Careers asks me to tag my tagged projects

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I tagged my projects in the projects section

[image]

But "Tag your projects" is still there in "Ways to improve your profile"

[image]

And also in the completeness report

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Technologies now look at both your custom tags as well as the project origin info.

Comment: "Tag your projects" is still there though.

Comment: It seems that this has finally been fixed.